# Angular 2 routing redirect not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a redirect defined in app-routing.module and have no ideas why is it not working. If I use a default path for ""(code that is currently commented out) instead of a redirect then it works fine.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: "actions",
            component: ActionsComponent
        },
        //{
        //    path: "",
        //    component: LoginComponent
        //}
        {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "/login",
            pathMatch: "full"
        }
    ])
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
```

})

Any ideas? Code is in http://plnkr.co/edit/y970zDKDZRIZ5LQA8v1T?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is working as intended according to the Angular 2 people @ https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12133

Basically the error message was misleading and I had to have a default path in the route. So changing the following in login-route.module.ts from

```
            children: [
                { path: "loginDetails", component: LoginDetailsComponent },
                { path: "moreLoginDetails", component: MoreLoginDetailsComponent }
            ]
```

to

```
           children: [
                { path: "loginDetails", component: LoginDetailsComponent },
                { path: "", component: MoreLoginDetailsComponent }
            ]
```

would fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your reproduction you don't have really /login path because the second router-outlet don't know which child of the login route should be process.

In the answer of @Ha Hoang if you comment below line :

```
{ path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" }
```

your app still work ! because (path: "") override in login-routing.module on line :

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }
```

but I think the way of @Ha Hoan is not logical because the path="" should not be load LoginComponent it should redirect to /login url and then path="login" should load LoginComponent my suggestion is :

In app-routing.module: use /login/loginDetails instead of /login

```
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/login/loginDetails",
    pathMatch: "full"
}
```

then your plunker work correct and the structure of the routing is better.
http://plnkr.co/edit/YENJ4Wm26qMty5mOR1dA?p=preview

Comment: The problem is I might want to have some logic in LoginComponent's ngOnInit to determine the route to take. So I do want it to load LoginComponent and not go directly to "/login/loginDetails".

Comment: I think you want have /login/loginDetails route but you don not want to get access to this route directly, that means you want to user first get /login then the LoginComponent refers the user to /login/loginDetails. YES ???

Answer (score 0):

You should be changed some things as follow:

1. In app-routing.module.ts: using 'login' instead of '/login'

   {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "login",
        pathMatch: "full"
   }
2. In app/login/login-routing.module:

   ```
       RouterModule.forChild([
       {
           path: 'login',
           children: [
               { path: "loginDetails", component: LoginDetailsComponent },
               { path: "moreLoginDetails", component: MoreLoginDetailsComponent }
           ]
       },
       { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
       ])
   ```

It works for me!

Comment: Can you please explain why what I have done initially did not work? Why did the Angular 2 documentation have "/" in their redirect path? And why can't I link "login" to LoginComponent instead of having to do  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }?

Comment: There are no leading slashes in the path. The router parses and builds the URL for us, allowing us to use relative and absolute paths when navigating between application views.

Comment: Also By setting ‘path’ to an empty string, we create a route that instantiates your login component  as the default path.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `/` from your path, e.g `/login` to `login`, just add this in your `index.html`

`<base href="/">`

If you need invalid URL to be redirected, you can you use,

`{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }`

Comment: If you see in the plnkr link above, I already have the href set.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reply to sigit_prayoga's comment, but if you use

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
```

Then you need to put it **at the bottom** of your routes, otherwise everything below it will redirect.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you have no route called `'login'`. So the router first goes to the empty `''`-route. Here he notices that he has to navigate to the `login`route, but he cannot found such a route. I think this should be the solution:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: "actions",
        component: ActionsComponent
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/login",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
])
```

Corrected plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xvt6RdoQWDFakT12ZNRH?p=preview

Comment: { path: "login", component: LoginComponent } has already been specified in the child route in login-routing.module. Does it need to be repeated again?

Comment: I updated the plunker so you do not have to repeat it. You can do it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gN3aVSIaO0emy0bdH69j?p=preview